# Problems viewing facebook page tab

Tags: view, facebook-page

I need help because now I can not see my facebook application.
I do not see the page, but I see the css code is not mine, as the following:

```
.dialog_body .dialog_option{padding:14px 0 7px 0}
.dialog_body .dialog_option input{width:13px;height:13px;padding:0;margin:0;vertical-align:bottom;position:relative;top:0;overflow:hidden}
.dialog_body .dialog_option .dialog_option_text{padding-left:5px;text-indent:-15px}
.friendshipPageLikes .mediaRow{padding-bottom:10px}
.friendshipPageLikesNoSubheader .label{display:none}
.friendshipRecommendationDoublePic{width:55px}
.fbTimelineAds .friendshipRecommendationDoublePic{width:74px}
.fbTimelineAds .friendshipRecommendationDoublePic .uiProfilePhoto{padding-right:5px}
.fbTimelineAds .uiTypeahead{margin-bottom:5px}
.friendshipRecommendationDoublePic .uiProfilePhoto{padding-right:1px}
#pagelet_friendship_wall .uiComposer ul{padding-left:5px}
#pagelet_friendship_status_text{line-height:15px;padding-top:4px;width:490px;color:#666}
.friendshipPageGroups{padding-top:8px;padding-bottom:8p
```

This app, you can clearly see with my account from your smartphone.

I tried several accounts of my business but I see the same thing.
May depend on what this error?

Comment: I discovered that the problem occurred only in the network of my company and therefore was not bound to a facebook account.
after a few days came back ok. I have not changed anything, Facebook probably has something correctly.
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this on a lot of Facebook pages too (including some of my own).

It has something to do with Facebook changing the URLs of the `<iframe>`s:

```
Before: www.facebook.com/pageusername?sk=app_YOUR_APP_ID

Now:    www.facebook.com/pageusername/app_YOUR_APP_ID
```

This issue gets solved if you change it to the old one in the Facebook permission dialog request.

Answer (score 0):

for me it randomly doesnt work with Chrome, but with Firefox instead! Might be some weird Javascript Facebook Bug.

There is also a bug report, have a look here:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/185936138199048?browse=search_4fc87b4f9afb20978011909

Answer (score 0):

This seem like, it only occurs on http. When you use https instead of http, it works as expected.